# How to fill missing month object in sorted array of object

Tags: javascript

Seeking help to generate a logic were user will select random data range (e.g. 06/2022 - 12/2023 - date object) and trigger request to backend which will return somewhat below data (response with missing month details) and from that I need to fill missing month object with dummy details.

e.g.: Imagine below data which is returned from backend [ACTUAL].

```
[   // Missing details from June till Sep 2022    
    {
        "Years": "2022",
        "Months": "Oct",
        ...
    },
    {
        "Years": "2022",
        "Months": "Nov",
        ...
    },
    {
        "Years": "2022",
        "Months": "Dec",
        ...
    },          // Missed Jan data
    {
        "Years": "2023",
        "Months": "Feb",
        ...
    }
    ...
]
```

Some magical logic and it should look like below [EXPECTED solution]

```
[
    {
        "Years": "2022",
        "Months": "Jun",
        ...
    },
    {
        "Years": "2022",
        "Months": "Jul",
        ...
    },
    {
        "Years": "2022",
        "Months": "Aug",
        ...
    },
    {
        "Years": "2022",
        "Months": "Sep",
        ...
    },
    {
        "Years": "2022",
        "Months": "Oct",
        ...
    },
    {
        "Years": "2022",
        "Months": "Nov",
        ...
    },
    {
        "Years": "2022",
        "Months": "Dec",
        ...
    },
    {
        "Years": "2023",
        "Months": "Jan",
        ...
    },
    ... // Until end data
    {
        "Years": "2023",
        "Months": "Dec",
        ...
    },
]
```

Comment: What did you try to solve this?

Comment: There are some important factors missing here like how was the first array created. and from your provided info, I think there must be a default complete array to compare the new array with then complete it according to the default array. did you get my thoughts here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to loop through the specified date range (from -> to) and increment by a month after each iteration. While iterating, you need to grab the short month and full year, check if you already have the data, and apply it to the results. If it is not found, create a new item and add it.

```js
const original = [    
  { "Years": "2022", "Months": "Oct", "Data": { exists: true } },
  { "Years": "2022", "Months": "Nov", "Data": { exists: true } },
  { "Years": "2022", "Months": "Dec", "Data": { exists: true } },
  // Missed Jan data
  { "Years": "2023", "Months": "Feb", "Data": { exists: true } }
];

const main = () => {
  const
    start = Date.parse('2022-06-01'), end = Date.parse('2023-12-01'),
    updated = applyMissingDates(original, start, end);
  console.log(updated);
};

const applyMissingDates = (data, fromDate, toDate) => {
  const result = [], currDate = new Date(fromDate);
  while (currDate <= toDate) {
    const
      year = getYear(currDate), month = getMonth(currDate),
      found = data.find(item =>
        item.Years === year && item.Months === month);
    result.push(found ? { ...found } : { Years: year, Months: month });
    currDate.setUTCMonth(currDate.getUTCMonth() + 1);
  }
  return result;
};

const getMonth = (date) => date.toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'short', timeZone: 'UTC' });

const getYear = (date) => date.getUTCFullYear().toString();

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```